# Java serialization, how identify and name one file for each object?

Tags: java, serialization, stream

I want to save severals files using Stream to serialize objects, with one serializable object per file.

The reason why I want have one file per object is that I have a list of these objects, I am on Android and at the start of the applicaiton I want load all saved objects, this is the easy part.

But during the execution I want add new elements in this list, and delete elements. And I want update the folder with my files in the same time.

So I supposed I have to create one file per object. But may be there is another solution ?

The main problem is : how name each file ? To avoid overwrite a file, ...

I first thinked that I will have to name my files depending the name of a String given by the user, but I will have to check if the name file is valid,...

So may be the solution is to just name my files with an integer, and at the first load, I just continue the counter from the higher file ?

I suppose my problem is frequent, so what are your solutions to write during the execution a dynamic list of objects ?

Thanks you

Comment: Does the order matter ?

Comment: @codeflush.dev not really